# Publishing artifact only after tests were successful

Tags: gradle

I've been fighting this problem for a long time and genuinely out of ideas. In my project I use the `maven-publish` plugin for publishing artifact to my repository:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
    id("maven-publish")
}
```

And also using Kotest to run tests:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Obviously, I want to publish artifacts only if all tests passed, so I add the following:

```kotlin
tasks.publish {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    mustRunAfter(tasks.test)
}
```

However, when I run `./gradlew clean build test publish` on the command line, the artifacts are always published before the tests run:

```
> Task :clean
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources
> Task :generatePomFileFor«project-name»Publication
> Task :compileKotlin
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :generateMetadataFileFor«project-name»Publication
> Task :publish«project-name»PublicationTo«repository-name»Repository
> Task :compileTestKotlin
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me long enough. Apparently, the `publish` task is not the one that actually publishes the jar, but the `publish«project-name»PublicationTo«repository-name»Repository`. However, this task is not available until after configuration, so the best I could do is:

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
  tasks.getByName("publish«project-name»PublicationTo«repository-name»Repository").dependsOn(tasks.test)
}
```

Comment: My mind is blown as to how Gradle could have such a massive flaw in it.

Answer (score 0):

This approach, although not ideal, also works:

Kotlin code:

```kotlin
tasks.filter {
    it.group == "publishing"
    //it.name.startsWith("publish")
}.forEach {
    it.dependsOn("test")
}
```

Groovy code:

```java
tasks.findAll {
    it.group == "publishing"
    //it.name.startsWith("publish")
}.each {
    it.dependsOn("test")
}
```

Comment: Using Gradle wrapper 8.5, I get an error trying to use this technique. The error is: `Could not find method filter() for arguments [build_9w5pa6s47faw7xhxiafaxzymv$_run_closure7@1aeb33a8] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.`